# jQuery: Writing Mega Menu with ToggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on building a Mega Menu for our site's header. I'm using jQuery to toggleClass to set active states for the "drawers". I am fairly new to jQuery and haven't gotten into a lot of the more complex ways to structure code, so my current implementation, I think, is very tedious/verbose and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this class toggling. Note that (at least at this point) I've chosen not to go the hover route but instead use click toggling. Hover menus can be a PITA.

Here is my CodePen with everything in it, include the jQuery in question:
http://codepen.io/ksherman/pen/YPMXJW

Here is the jQuery block:

```
$('#admissions').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.admissionsNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#degrees, #apply, #visit, #campus, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#degrees').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.degreesNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav, .admissionsNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #apply, #visit, #campus, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#apply').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.applyNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav, .admissionsNav, .degreesNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#visit, #campus, #about, #search, #admissions, #degrees').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#visit').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.visitNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav, .admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #campus, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#campus').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.campusNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.aboutNav, .searchNav, .admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #visit, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#about').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.aboutNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.searchNav, .admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #visit, #campus,  #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#search').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.searchNav').toggleClass('active');
    $('.admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #visit, #campus, #about').parent().removeClass('active');
});

$('#body').click( function () {
    $('.admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #visit, #campus, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine those into one function, and call it for all the buttons.

```
var menus = ['admissions', 'degrees', 'apply', 'visit', 'campus', 'about', 'search'];

function menuClick(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $('.' + e.target.id + 'Nav').toggleClass('active');
    var otherMenus = menus.filter(function (item) { return item !== e.target.id });
    otherMenus.forEach(function (menu) {
        $('.' + menu + 'Nav').removeClass('active');
        $('#' + menu).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
}
menus.forEach(function (menu) {
    $('#' + menu).click(menuClick);
});
$('#body').click( menuClick );
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYNNgM?editors=001)

Comment: That looks so much better! Building functions is definitely where I have a lot more learning to do. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! [repeating yourself](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself) is normally a bad sign.

Comment: Hi XinUmbrails, any ideas why the search drawer sometimes has trouble opening? http://codepen.io/ksherman/pen/YPMXJW/

Comment: Ah yes, because there's another element inside that nav. I was relying on only a nav with an id being clickable. It's easily fixable by changing the otherMenus filter to use the jquery 'closest'. [See this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yydPgq)

Answer (score 2):

Combine the common elements into a single method:

Javascript:

```
$('#awesome_ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    //hide all
    $('.admissionsNav, .degreesNav, .applyNav, .visitNav, .campusNav, .aboutNav, .searchNav').removeClass('active');
    $('#admissions, #degrees, #apply, #visit, #campus, #about, #search').parent().removeClass('active');

    //show wanted one
    $('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'Nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="primary">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-12 columns">
                <ul id="awesome_ul">
```

Comment: Wow, that's nice and simple. It doesn't toggle them back off if you click the button again though, which is something I'd want to preserve.